# Print a cloned div in new window

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the following code for printing a div in a new window:

```
$('#PrintNews').bind('click', function () {          
        var approot = '<%=AppRoot %>';
        var printContents = new $("#divToPrint").clone();
        var myWindow = window.open("", "popup", "width=800,height=600,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes," +
             "toolbar=no,directories=no,location=no,menubar=no,status=no,left=250px,top=80px");
         var doc = myWindow.document;

         doc.open();
         $(printContents).find("#PrintNews").remove();
         $(printContents).find("#bottom").remove();
         doc.write("<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd\">");
         doc.write("<html>");
         doc.write("<head>");
         doc.write("<link href='" + approot + "/Themes/print.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />");
         doc.write("<link href='" + approot + "/Themes/secretaryPortal.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />");
         doc.write("</head>");
         doc.write("<body style='font: 11pt/1.2 Arial !important;'>");
         doc.write("<div class='story'>");
         doc.write($(printContents).html());
         doc.write("</div>");
         doc.write("</body>");
         doc.write("</html>");
         myWindow.document.close();
         myWindow.focus();
         myWindow.print();
         myWindow.close();           
        });

});
```

It does open the print dialog But the page isn't with the original css.
if i change the 4 last lines to:

```
         doc.document.close();
         doc.focus();
         doc.print();
         doc.close();
```

It opens the page with the right CSS But the print dialog is not opened.
i get an error saying `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'close' of undefined`

I have to open it in a new window cause i need to re-size to print dialog, i am aware of @media print

Comment: Which `.close()` causes that error?

Comment: I figured up that the close isn't the problem. If I mark up the two last lines (print and close) the window is opened with the right design, if i press ctrl-p it's print it just fine. The problem is that: if I keep the last two lines the windows is opened with printing dialog But the printing dialog contains the doc with no css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your description instead of :

```
doc.document.close();
doc.focus();
doc.print();
doc.close();
```

use:

```
myWindow.focus();
myWindow.print();
myWindow.close();
```

Comment: i get the folowing error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: doc is not defined "

Comment: one last try ! @user1454961

Comment: myWindow.location.reload();
myWindow.focus();
myWindow.print();  Works! BUT the window is not closing after the print click.. and if i put the line  myWindow.close(); after the print then the css is not loading, strange. isn't it?

Comment: try putting close before print ! @user1454961

Comment: Working with that code:myWindow.focus();
             myWindow.print();
            myWindow.close(); maybe consider to edit your answer? thanks very much

Answer (score 1):

This is the final solution: *Thanks to Yussuf above

```
  $('#PrintNews').bind('click', function () {          
        var approot = '<%=AppRoot %>';
        var printContents = new $("#divToPrint").clone();
        var myWindow = window.open("", "popup", "width=800,height=600,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes," +
             "toolbar=no,directories=no,location=no,menubar=no,status=no,left=250px,top=80px");             

         $(printContents).find("#PrintNews").remove();
         $(printContents).find("#bottom").remove();
         myWindow.document.write("<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd\">");
         myWindow.document.write("<html>");
         myWindow.document.write("<head>");
         myWindow.document.write("<link href='" + approot + "/Themes/print.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />");
         myWindow.document.write("<link href='" + approot + "/Themes/secretaryPortal.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />");
         myWindow.document.write("</head>");
         myWindow.document.write("<body style='font: 11pt/1.2 Arial !important;'>");
         myWindow.document.write("<div class='story'>");
         myWindow.document.write($(printContents).html());
         myWindow.document.write("</div>");
         myWindow.document.write("</body>");
         myWindow.document.write("</html>");
        myWindow.focus();
         myWindow.print();
        myWindow.close();
        });
```